# How to support all javascript api methods of Browser Extension in content scripts

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to user this method but I'm not able to retrieve the object from browser in Firefox.

```js
browser.cookies.getAll
```

Can you please tell me what to use instead?

Comment: It helps greatly if you include minimal code demonstrating the issue.

Comment: are you calling it?

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't help with this